# Import project to Visual Studio online

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms project in Visual Studio and have recently got another laptop. I would like to be able to edit the project when using my work laptop so I searched online and found Visual Studio Online.

The problem is I don't know how to import my current project into the Visual Studio online to get it on the other laptop. I have tried watching tutorials but all others explain how to create a new project and couldn't find any tutorials online that explain it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to [sign up for Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/) and create a new project:

Make sure you select Team Foundation Version Control during this step.

[image: Creating a new project in TFS]

Once the project is created, you can head over to Visual Studio and make sure you're connected to TFS (Team Foundation Server).

Open the Team Explorer panel if it isn't already open (you can find it in View->Team Explorer) and click "Connect"

[image: Opening the Team Explorer in VS]

Once you do that, a window will open that will allow you to sign into your Microsoft account that you used to create the TFS server. Once signed in, you can select your project and click "Connect"

[image: Connect to TFS project]

Your project should open in the Team Explorer panel where you should then click "Configure Workspace"

[image: Configuring workspace in TFS]

Click "Advanced Options" and then change the Local Folder to point to the folder that contains the solution you want in source control.

[image: Custom folder]

Click okay and say no when it asks you if you want to get latest from source control.

You can now go to the "Pending Changes" page in the Team Explorer and click on "Detected XX add(s)" and then click "Promote" in the resulting dialog.

[image: Promote changes]

The final step is to add a comment and check in everything!

[image: Check in]

Your code is now in source control!

From here you can proceed like normal in setting up TFS on your new computer and getting your code from TFS!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The screenshots also helped a lot!

Comment: @Dan no problem. Glad I could help!